# Is voltage basically the measure of the strength (or density) of an electromagnetic field? And does an increase in voltage increase the amperage?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, voltage, ferromagnetism

I have been in the process of fully understanding what is generally accepted as truth by the scientific community regarding voltage, watts, and amperage. Most engineers seem to say to simply use the formulas, don't ask about theory.

Is voltage conceptually similar to the feeling of pressure between the same poles of 2 ferromagnetic masses?

Also it seems that an increase in voltage should increase amperage because more coulombs would pass through a point in a second with more pressure of voltage. Does it cause that to happen? If not, why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't fully understand your comparison with magnetic forces. Would you mind clearing it out in more detail?

Comment: It seems that voltage is only present in charge along a conductor as a change in the strength of the field (don't know if that is an electromagnetic or electromotive field) around the conductor. Is voltage measurable or quantifiable in any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Voltage is just the electric potential energy difference between two points in space expressed per charge. In other words, if two points in space have voltage difference $V$ between them, then a charge $q$ that moves between those two points in space experiences a change in electric potential energy $\Delta U=qV$.

For circuits, a larger potential difference across the ends of a circuit can result in a larger current (which I believe is what you are calling amperage). For example, for ohmic resistors, the equation $V=IR$ holds, where $V$ is the voltage drop across the resistor, $R$ is the resistance, and $I$ is the resulting current that moves through the resistor. So as you can see, a larger voltage can yield a larger current (although this is not true for all materials).

Addressing your title question, we can relate the voltage and electric field through the equation 
$$\mathbf E=-\nabla V$$
or
$$V=\int\mathbf E\cdot\text d\mathbf x$$
the electric field relates to how the voltage changes over space. In this way, you can think of the field as having units of Volts per meter.

As for your question about magnetism, the analog is something called the magnetic vector potential, but I don't think this is what you are interested in. Voltage is not a pressure, and it is not related to a static magnetic force.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that voltage can change amperage...although that confuses the situation a little. Mainly in the process of figuring out if the field around a conductor is the only measurable voltage in a coulomb. Is it? And why does the field get generated? Also, if an electron travels through air between two points with different voltage potentials, what shape is the field?

Comment: @01GOD The comments in an answer are not the place to ask and answer new questions. If you have another question, then ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The value of voltage is unrelated to the strength of the electric field: this is because the electric field is the *gradient* of the voltage:
$$
\vec E=-\vec\nabla V\, .
$$
Thus it is perfectly possible to have $0$ voltage somewhere while having a non-zero electric field there, since what matters is the change in $V$, not $V$ itself.

Voltage is a measure of work done by unit charge: it’s not a force and therefore bears no relation with pressure.